# Python Google Cloud Natural Language API returns Bad Gateway error with status 502

Tags: python, google-cloud-python, google-natural-language

I'm working on a project using Python(3.6) and Django(2) in which I need to process all text files from a directory using Google's Natural Language API python's Client.
At the moment, there are 30 text files in my folder for testing purpose, the programs perform sentiment_analysis on 28 files but when reached 29th file it returns an error like below:

> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
>
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta2/documents:analyzeSentiment?alt=json returned "Bad Gateway">
>
> [19/Dec/2018 10:08:41] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 15145

Here's how I'm using the python's client:

```
def nlp_text_manager(text_path, name):
    text = text_path
    txt = Path(text_path).read_text(encoding='cp1252')
    service = discovery.build('language', 'v1beta2', credentials=credentials)
    service_request = service.documents().analyzeSentiment(
        body={
            'document': {
                'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
                'content': txt
            }
        }
    )
    response = service_request.execute()
    return response
```

The Traceback points out the `response = service_request.execute()` line inside the 
`nlp_text_manager` function.

What can be wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it be possible to share the contents of the file with us? Is it possible that the encoding or file format is different, or if there are special characters in the text?

Comment: This is the file where it raised the error: https://file.io/L9TThq

Comment: The file is 404.